# Pausing and starting Bootstrap 4 carousel for slide with video

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel

Having read numerous threads about this I can't find the solution. Can anybody provide some guidance please?

Standard Bootstrap 4 carousel. I am trying to pause the 1st slide for the duration of the video then resume the standard carousel action.

```
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
              <video id="myVideo" class="video-fluid" autoplay muted>
                <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/Tropical.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
              </video>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/1600x400?text=Slide+2); background-position: center center;">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/1600x400?text=Slide+3); background-position: center center;">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>

  </div>
```

And the following to - in theory - stop and start the carousel.

```
 // Stop/start carousel when video playing
    $('#myVideo').on('play', function (e) {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            pause: true,
            interval: false
            });
        });
    $('#myVideo').on('stop pause ended', function (e) {
        $("#myCarousel").carousel({
            cycle: true,
            interval: 1000,
            });
        });
```

My problem is I can't get it to work reliably. Only using `pause: true` doesn't seem to stop the carousel. I found I had to use`pause: true` and `interval: false`. And then I find I can't resume the carousel using `cycle: true` and `interval: 1000` in the 'stop pause ended' section.

However I could advance to the next slide with `$("#myCarousel").carousel('next');` - but that doesn't do any good though as it only moves forward one, it doesn't resume the carousel.

I know I can stop the carousel moving by removing `data-ride` but that stops it permanently, all I'm trying to achieve is for the carousel to pause for the duration of the video in the 1st slide.

Aside from this the next thing I'm unclear on is how to start the video again the next time the user cycles through to the 1st slide in the carousel.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this with the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slider = $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    });
    $('#myVideo').on('play', function (e) {
        slider.carousel('pause');
    });
    $('#myVideo').on('stop pause ended', function (e) {
        slider.carousel({ 'pause': false });
        slider.carousel('next');
    });
});
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
    if (currentIndex == 1) {
        $('#myVideo').get(0).play()
    }
});
```

Which seems a little messy but does the job:

- Default 5 second carousel interval
- Carousel paused for duration of video
- Carousel resumes automatically after video finishes
- When carousel gets around to the 1st slide again the video plays starts playing again

There are all sorts of issues I never considered with this; for example if you don't want the video out but use a < prev next > control the default 5 second interval doesn't work since the video is still playing in the background. So I guess for completeness the controls should also trigger  `slider.carousel({ 'pause': false });` and `slider.carousel('next');`.